# How i can read Barcode Prefix from Barcode Scanner Module

Tags: c#, serial-port, barcode-scanner, uart

```
I have a barcode Scanner and I want to read the Barcode Prefix from the Hardware
```

on the hardware set, a two character like "01" or "AA" as a Prefix

I receive from comport "\u0002\0\0\u0001\031" what is it? Hex? Or Unicode?

Hex must be Like this : 0x30   // 0
0x31   // 1
[Documentation](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/d/dd/Barcode_Scanner_Module_Setting_Manual_EN.pdf)

> Here is my Write method an the Comport

```
public void GetPrefix(SerialPort serialPort)
    {
        try
        {
            if (serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.WriteLine("Open");
                byte[] my_byte = new byte[9];
                my_byte[0] = 0x7E;//Header
                my_byte[1] = 0x00;//Header
                my_byte[2] = 0x08;//Type
                my_byte[3] = 0x01;//Lens 
                my_byte[4] = 0x63;//add
                my_byte[5] = 0x71;//add
                my_byte[6] = 0x08;//data  : The data read
                my_byte[7] = 0xAB;//CRC
                my_byte[8] = 0xCD;//
                serialPort.Write(my_byte, 0, 9);
                rx_message =  serialPort.ReadExisting();
                Console.WriteLine(rx_message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

    }
```

> Here is a DataReceivedHandler method

```
 private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            unicode = sp.ReadExisting(); //Read the data
            Console.WriteLine(unicode);
            
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: The response is a string.  The 'u' indicates it is 4 nibbles (2 bytes) and it follows the scanner documentation.  Nothing says it must be 0x30.  It is what the vendor puts in his documentation.

Answer (score 0):

What you received is what is written on page 68 of the document.

It indicates that the processing of the write command you sent has completed normally.
However, this is a strange phenomenon. The documentation only lists addresses from 0x0000 to 0x00E5, and the 0x6371(or 0x7163?) you specify is a private address.
You may have broken something in the barcode scanner by doing this.

And you sent a write command, which you wouldn't be able to use to read your intended barcode prefix.

You should use the read command, which is written from page 64 of the document.
By reading 0x11 bytes from 0x0060 of the address, you will be able to check the presence/absence, length, and data of the prefix.
Details of them can be found on pages 87-88 of the documentation.